# Google Drive API - autologin of google account xyz@gmail.com

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

My requirement is to access google drive api with single gmail account.e.g. xyz@gmail.com ,all the documents being uploaded should be stored in this account . 
The code I have written needs authentication of an individual.

```
Code :
******
var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID;
var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBqbBvT5sm_mDUMuBLJP0UvfCKU1EROGzQ';
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
 }

function checkAuth() {
var options = {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    immediate: true
};
  gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
var authorizeMsg =document.getElementById('authorize-msg');

if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    authorizeMsg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    makeApiCall();
} else {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
}
}

  function handleAuthClick(event) {
var options = {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    immediate: false
   };
     gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
     return false;
  }

function makeApiCall() {  
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);   
}

function makeRequest() {
 var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({'maxResults': 5 });
 request.execute(function(resp) {   
    var html="";
for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
        var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
        var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
        var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
        var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
        var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;

        var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
         html += "<li>"; 
     html+="Title : "+titulo +" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Modified Date : "+fechaUpd+" <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Link : "+"<a href='"+userAltLink+"'>"+userAltLink+"</a>";
    html+="</li>";
    }
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=html;
});
```

}

I want the default configuration for xyz@gmail.com. on page load it should by default login using this email account

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @JaromandaX See edited question

Comment: you cannot make this securely without a backend. instead look at apps script its trivial to make it there with the permission config you want.

Comment: @ZigMandel Can I use the refresh token to achieve this? since it never expires. I can use it to generate access token for my account.and use it for further gapi calls

Comment: yes but like ixsaid its very insecure to do so without a backend.